# How to set up a MEI in Brazil

Tags: paperwork, brazil

I have recently received a Visto Permanente and can stay in Brazil for at least nine years. Now, I want to set up a MEI via [this link](http://www.portaldoempreendedor.gov.br), but am told I first need to check with SEBREA, where I find [this page](http://www.sebrae.com.br/sites/PortalSebrae/ufs/ap/artigos/%C3%89-estrangeiro%3F-Voc%C3%AA-tamb%C3%A9m-pode-ser-um-MEI), which tells me I first need to get a "Declaração do Imposto de Renda Pessoa Física". However, they don't tell me how I get this.

How do I get a Declaração do Imposto de Renda Pessoa Física?

Update: The software to fill in this "Declaracao" can be downloaded from [here](http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/interface/cidadao/irpf/2016/download). However, because my CPF was not yet 'active' last year, filling in this declaration and submitting it is not accepted by the system.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have in fact submitted a declaration.

If so, this may help:

- If you have security code + certificate you can use this link (https://cav.receita.fazenda.gov.br/eCAC/publico/login.aspx) to log in and get the copy.
- If you filled your tax in the computer you can try to find a copy in the computer itself.
- Take a photo id with you and head to the Receita Federal office in your city to get a copy. You have to make an appointment either through the phone number 146 or online (https://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/interface/agendamento/agendamento).

More info can be found here:

http://www.konkero.com.br/financas-pessoais/seus-direitos/como-tirar-2a-via-da-declaracao-de-imposto-de-renda

Comment: What does the link say? You should quote, and translate, the relevant parts here.

Comment: Thanks. However, I have not submitted a declaration, if with 'declaration' you mean "Declaração do Imposto de Renda Pessoa Física". That's exactly the step I'm not clear on now. Where and/or how do I fill that in? You suggest I can fill it in on my computer. Where do I download the relevant software?

Comment: That's the one. Not everyone needs to fill in the tax return form, I don't know if this is your case. Check the conditions here => http://www.ebc.com.br/noticias/economia/2016/02/imposto-de-renda-2016-o-que-voce-precisa-saber-para-fazer-sua-declaracao
If you don't have to fill in, then this shouldn't prevent you from open a MEI since you don't have to provide a document you are not required to fill in. I would search an accountant to get further advice on this. It will pay in the long run.

Comment: Thanks. An accountant might be a good idea. However, SEBRAE's website does state I need this declaration to get a MEI (see my link).

Comment: You're right, in this case I think they would require you to fill in the declaration of exempt (Isento). It is indeed a declaration that must be filled.